# Get a list of required fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm showing all attributes of a `Post` model as an HTML table header by using:

```
Post.column_names #=> ['id','name','status', 'created_at',....]
```

But I need to pick only those fields that are required in `Post` model i.e having `validates: presence: true`

Is there a way to pick the required fields?

Comment: Well, look at validators then.

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
Post.validators
```

It will return all declared validator in your Model.
like 
`<ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x00000007b12568 @attributes=[..]`

You can iterate over it or directly access like `Post.validators.first.attributes`

Hope It's help you.